# Apple AWT Internal Exception: -[NSView CGLPBufferObj]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc73d201960

Tags: ios, jogl

I'm trying to start an application with some native jogl libraries under mac. It runs on linux and windows. The error message is:

```
2012-10-26 16:35:49.160 java[1440:1703] invalid drawable
2012-10-26 16:35:49.163 java[1440:1703] -[NSView CGLPBufferObj]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc73d201960
2012-10-26 16:35:49.164 java[1440:1703] Apple AWT Internal Exception: -[NSView CGLPBufferObj]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc73d201960
2012-10-26 16:35:49.165 java[1440:1703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSView CGLPBufferObj]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc73d201960'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff929e60a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f7533f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92a7c6ea -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff929d45ce ___forwarding___ + 414
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff929d43b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c6395be -[NSOpenGLContext setPixelBuffer:cubeMapFace:mipMapLevel:currentVirtualScreen:] + 59
    6   libjogl_desktop.jnilib              0x00000001284708cb setContextPBuffer + 203
    7   libjogl_desktop.jnilib              0x00000001284d428b Java_jogamp_opengl_macosx_cgl_CGL_setContextPBuffer__JJ + 43
    8   ???                                 0x000000010790ef90 0x0 + 4421906320
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Process finished with exit code 134
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is this iOS related, or has it been mistagged?

Comment: I tried this tutorial: https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-3 with these libraries: group: 'org.jogamp.jogl', name: 'jogl-all', version: '2.0-rc10'; group: 'org.jogamp.jogl', name: 'jogl-all', version: '2.0-rc10', classifier: 'natives-macosx-universal'; group: 'org.jogamp.gluegen', name: 'gluegen-rt', version: '2.0-rc10'; group: 'org.jogamp.gluegen', name: 'gluegen-rt', version: '2.0-rc10', classifier: 'natives-macosx-universal'
Doesn't work!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm running into the same thing.

Comment: No solution yet! My guess is that there is a problem with mac-osx, sun-java-7 and newest jogl-libs. Don't find any java-6-jdk for mac to downgrade :-(